# Output error when comparing anagrams strings

Tags: java, string, anagram

I was solving an anagram question on geek for geeks but I think the output format is not similar  as shown in question over all my code is correct but there is a problem in test cases so see my code and tell me what's wrong in this.

```java
/*package whatever //do not write package name here */
    
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class GFG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        boolean isAnagram = true;
        while (t-- > 0) {
            String a = sc.nextLine();
            String b = sc.nextLine();

            int al[] = new int[256];
            for (char c : a.toCharArray()) {
                int index = (int) c;
                al[index]++;
            }
            for (char c : b.toCharArray()) {
                int index = (int) c;
                al[index]--;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                if (al[i] != 0) {
                    isAnagram = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isAnagram) {
                System.out.println("1");
            } else {
                System.out.println("0");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output of custom case:

[image: custom case 1]

[image: custom case 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `boolean isAnagram = true;` inside `while (t-- > 0)` loop.

Currently, if in the first test the text is not an anagram, existing code does not set `isAnagram` to `true`.

Also, the two input strings cannot be anagrams if their lengths are different, and explicit casting of `char` to `int` is redundant.

That being said, the contents of the `while` loop should be updated as follows:

```java
while (t-- > 0) {
    String a = sc.nextLine();
    String b = sc.nextLine();

    boolean isAnagram = a.length() == b.length();
    if (isAnagram) {
        int al[] = new int[256];
        for (int c : a.toCharArray()) {
            al[c]++;
        }

        for (int c : b.toCharArray()) {
            al[c]--;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < al.length; i++) {
            if (al[i] != 0) {
                isAnagram = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(isAnagram ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if *two strings are anagrams*, you can compare the *two sorted character arrays* of those strings:

```java
String a = "chinmay";
String b = "maychin";

char[] aArr = a.toCharArray();
char[] bArr = b.toCharArray();

Arrays.sort(aArr);
Arrays.sort(bArr);

boolean isAnagram = Arrays.equals(aArr, bArr);

System.out.println(isAnagram); // true
```

---

<sup>See also: [How do you check if a word has an anagram that is a palindrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67082201/15675591)</sup>