# How do you check if a word has an anagram that is a palindrome?

Tags: java, string, cpu-word, palindrome, anagram

How do you compare a palindromic word to one of the newly formed words of an anagram?

And how do you grab one of the newly formed words for it to be compared to the input word?

This is my code:

```java
public class SampleCode2 {
    public static boolean isPalindromic(String word, String mark) {
        if (word.length() == 0) {
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            String newMark = mark + word.charAt(i);
            String newLetters = word.substring(0, i) +
                    word.substring(i + 1);
        }

        String ifPalindrome = ""; //will store here the reversed string
        String original = word; //will store here the original input word

        //to reverse the string
        for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ifPalindrome += word.charAt(i);
        }

        //to compare the reversed string to the anagram
        if (word.equals(ifPalindrome)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean check = isPalindromic("mmaad", "");
        System.out.println(check);
    }
}
```

It's not yet done because the permutation and comparison won't work. The output is displaying `false`, I need it to be `true` because the anagram of `MMAAD` is `madam`. And I have to check if `madam` is indeed a palindrome of `mmaad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So What I did is used HashMap instead of creating `words` from the given `word`
A String can be of `even` or `odd` length

---

If "EVEN" String is palindrome then every "character" in the `String` will appear `even` times 
eg: String str = maam : m=2, a=2

---

If "ODD" String is a palindrome then there will only be 1 character of `odd` occurrence and the rest will occur `even` times.
eg: String str = mmaad: m=2,a=2,d=1

---

To store the Occurrence of the Characters in the String we will use HashMap  where Character of the String is the `KEY` and its occurrence is `VALUE`

```
HashMap<Character,Integer> mapChar = new HashMap<>();
```

And we will add each Character in the `HashMap` with the number of times it has appeared in the String.

Now we will check if the `String length` is "even" or "odd"
if "EVEN" Length String  we know that every character will appear `EVEN` times and if any time a character appears "ODD" times we return `false` i.e It's not a Palindrome

```java
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entries : mapChar.entrySet()) {
    if (entries.getValue() % 2 != 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If "ODD" Length String we know that only one Character will appear `odd` time and the rest will be of `EVEN` Occurrence 
And if there are 2 characters that occur `odd` times then its not a palindrome

```java
// Number of times odd value Character as occurred
int occur1 = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entries : mapChar.entrySet()) {
    if (entries.getValue() % 2 == 1) {
        occur1++;
        if (occur1 > 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the whole Code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    boolean check = isPalindromic("malayalam", "");
    System.out.println(check);
}
```

```java
public static boolean isPalindromic(String word, String mark) {
    boolean isPal = true;
    if (word.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    HashMap<Character, Integer> mapChar = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char ch = word.charAt(i);
        if (mapChar.containsKey(ch)) {
            mapChar.put(ch, mapChar.get(ch) + 1);
        } else {
            mapChar.put(ch, 1);
        }
    }
    if (word.length() % 2 == 0) {
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entries : mapChar.entrySet()) {
            if (entries.getValue() % 2 != 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        int occur1 = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entries : mapChar.entrySet()) {
            if (entries.getValue() % 2 == 1) {
                occur1++;
                if (occur1 > 1) {
                    isPal = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return isPal;
}
```

output:

```
mmaa
Is Palindrome: true
mmaad
Is Palindrome: true
niti
Is Palindrome: false
```

Comment: You could save about 75% procedural boilerplate by streaming and filtering with a [BiPredicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a list of *anagrams* of a word that are *palindromes*, you can split this task into two parts: first get a list of the character permutations of that word `List<String>`, i.e. a list of anagrams, and then filter those strings that are palindromes. For example, for the `mmaad` string, the palindromes are:

```
madam
amdma
```

Getting a list of permutations is an *expensive operation* for *large strings*, since the number of permutations is a *factorial* of the *string length*. For example, for the `mmaad` string, there are 120 permutations. Filtering palindromes after that is cheaper.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVZLb9s4EL77VxA5UYEib3x0mmCLosAW3WADpLciB0Ya23QoUiCpBEaR357OkJKirCVFW2CB8mBJ9Dy@eX3kXjyKs33x8PIiy8pYz/a4kdVequz0YnG057wFUWafjFKQe2PduMwX7W/D28ViUdX3SuYsV8I5di2kZj8WDFez77zw@Hg0smAl/stRUert9zsm7NYljTCt5ZIp6TwzG1bgU@rcswpsWZMFo10nuAV/09vnJ2UpRHGSdAI9ixHmh@j06kiiCYgP6m6k8mBZJZTUhTUluGP9KMPRDDu7YtLddMK0lwzaNbWvaj9gy9jPIt/x24PzUGYotl5XiNsrnVwE8edFeCxPT6P2KfuzElaUjPw7U9sc6BVDTTHZB5Yb7akirrbWbIUHDEZal3XaFnxtNXvagd9hqPjz1gxGxEQvA63mcqDE98YoEPptEmLiydq/Si2sRYBY63yHEeSYREdfAUHQ6YQxAdgtJObYJf2Z5aaAG4P7jieZNx/JFG9SRKuJquvSoSJI9EgJ2SDM4PUetlJrAutN2ChlUSgYAdUVzQq9Bf5HGgFmCvTW79iSrQZLn5sSCwbB4mvga2w1i51/xnCIfMocYOEK/KxA18rLEoEeexZKXQuP/SKp9YL77/KOXV42728AnTGUYud3/3MjiekRHql3399Uh/2NNttRPmKB36LThtthiplCTNei@oA2YAs2beK7GiCrUlTfzD/3@1jx/@y059xCZcGB9rFeoKDED5x1ovAjLKOWXhHtCRGqZmbD9yn71KYakxaN8NiU@7skmUSWx@On10now40jaOT567GFLimpPBlmXwtFjd0mWKR@8kCeHI09biJUHHraGZj1oMo5/XueBqFVQoGHjfGzpOfd1XhYUcOS3zBD9NLmP51SlRlkIRlpQ1pPJiIfT85GCY9F4ah13uJcvY/z@AzEswgHxjhgD3BwcxT9TmARkeqEQm/FgTUN965ue6Qi5hVhpmeGXm8BSzofe2dOGw2RJykL63VDZe4rHJJZKdjj/DNEbiVE4sC8T/Zkfzq6MH7MQtwfPtYyHZpgl7MDpqXhCclSP0Dxl3A7MnrVZ62phc4yvJ18VCrk65e0VjO1GvZEjffln@fRBlL1e2P869QxytXHVIFXOeWAkwZRYsOMSNHhVjh1IMyzP3VvpX7BPo2H21teG7vFNJ1KjRp9ZtT1/OQkDaV9FKoGN5iWrD3oh7HMu9HPKkl7c3l@efkJ)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // list of distinct permutations
    getPermutations("mmaad")
            // Stream<String>
            .stream()
            // filter palindromes
            .filter(str -> isPalindrome(str))
            // output
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

```java
/**
 * @param str source string, may contain surrogate pairs.
 * @return whether the source string is a palindrome.
 */
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    // array of characters of the string
    int[] chars = str.codePoints().toArray();
    return IntStream
            // iterate from the beginning to the middle of the string
            .range(0, chars.length / 2)
            // compare the characters: first - last, second - penultimate
            .allMatch(i -> chars[i] == chars[chars.length - i - 1]);
}
```

```java
/**
 * @param str source string, may contain surrogate pairs.
 * @return a list of distinct permutations of characters of the source string.
 */
public static List<String> getPermutations(String str) {
    // array of characters of the string
    int[] chars = str.codePoints().toArray();
    return IntStream.range(0, chars.length)
            // Stream<List<Map<Integer,String>>>
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, chars.length)
                    // represent each character as Map<Integer,String>
                    .mapToObj(j -> Map.of(j, Character.toString(chars[j])))
                    // collect a list of maps
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            // reduce a stream of lists to a single list
            .reduce((list1, list2) -> list1.stream()
                    // summation of pairs of elements,
                    // i.e. maps, from two lists
                    .flatMap(map1 -> list2.stream()
                            // filter out those keys
                            // that are already present
                            .filter(map2 -> map2.keySet().stream()
                                    .noneMatch(map1::containsKey))
                            // join entries of two maps
                            .map(map2 -> {
                                Map<Integer, String> map =
                                        new LinkedHashMap<>();
                                map.putAll(map1);
                                map.putAll(map2);
                                return map;
                            }))
                    // collect into a single list
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            // List<Map<Integer,String>>
            .orElse(List.of(Map.of(0, str)))
            // Stream<Map<Integer,String>>
            .stream()
            // map of strings to a single string
            .map(map -> String.join("", map.values()))
            .distinct()
            // list of distinct permutations
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [How to create all permutations of tuples without mixing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66755532/15613375)

• [Reverse string printing method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67067763/15613375)</sup>